# Changing color of pin icon marker on CartoDB?

Tags: carto, markers

[image]I am interested to use the pin icon (see attached image) in my cartodb map (cluster type).

Can someone tell me how do I change the color of the pin to reflect categorical data? I tried to click img fill but it the button is not active when I select the pin icon as my marker type.

Comment: @ramiroaznar do you know the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a cluster map clicking on cluster map in the Wizard, and then adding at the beginning of your CartoCSS code `marker-file` (in my case I have used [this url](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/43/Blue_circle_for_diabetes.svg)) as Jorge said. Secondly, add in every bucket a style (in my case, because the marker is a circle I have to change the `marker-line-color` property). You will end up with a CartoCSS code like this one:

```
/** cluster + custom marker visualization */

#populated_places{
  marker-width: 12;
  marker-fill: #FD8D3C;
  marker-line-width: 1.5;
  marker-fill-opacity: 1;
  marker-line-opacity: 1;
  marker-line-color: #fff;
  marker-allow-overlap: true;
  marker-file: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/43/Blue_circle_for_diabetes.svg);

  [src = 'bucketC'] {
    marker-line-width: 5;
    marker-width: 24;
    marker-line-color: #d1eeea;
  } 

  [src = 'bucketB'] {
    marker-line-width: 5;
    marker-width: 44;
    marker-line-color: #68abb8;
  } 

  [src = 'bucketA'] {
    marker-line-width: 5;
    marker-width: 64;
    marker-line-color: #2a5674;
  } 
}

#populated_places::labels { 
  text-size: 0; 
  text-fill: #fff; 
  text-opacity: 0.8;
  text-name: [points_count]; 
  text-face-name: 'DejaVu Sans Book'; 
  text-halo-fill: #FFF; 
  text-halo-radius: 0; 

  [src = 'bucketC'] {
    text-size: 10;
    text-halo-radius: 0.5;
  }

  [src = 'bucketB'] {
    text-size: 15;
    text-halo-radius: 0.5;
  }

  [src = 'bucketA'] {
    text-size: 20;
    text-halo-radius: 0.5;
  }

  text-allow-overlap: true;

  [zoom>11]{ text-size: 16; }
  [points_count = 1]{ text-size: 0; }
}
```

And [here](https://team.cartodb.com/u/ramirocartodb/viz/07b2dc2c-3edf-11e6-bf6f-0ea31932ec1d/public_map) you have the resulting map.

Comment: Does this work if I am using a category map?

Comment: Your marker effect seems interesting. I will explore it when I have the time. Thank you ramino.

Comment: Do you know how to change the marker line width? This is the URL https://sengyapglobalmomentum.cartodb.com/viz/e9c2796a-fbcd-11e5-8d27-0ecfd53eb7d3/public_map I am using. I cannot seem to increase the marker line width despite changing it to 20.

Comment: First, about mixing cluster and categorical maps. Cluster maps work aggregating data points, it does not aggregate markers depending on (categorical) values. In my map, I use the word category just to color the different clusters. BUT what you can do is creating a new dataset for each category. Then represent each layer as clusters. 

Secondly, what you are looking for is the `marker-line-width` property. [Here](https://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-platform/cartocss/properties/) you have all the CartoCSS properties.

Comment: I am using marker-line-width but there is no line despite me setting the width as 20. The color is set as black, and the marker line opacity is set as 1, so I should be able to see the marker line. However, it is not showing up on my map. Any ideas why @ramino? Thank you for your help.

Comment: You need to add this property in each bucket. Like this:
`[src = 'bucketA'] {
    marker-line-width: 5;
    marker-width: 64;
    marker-line-color: #2a5674;
  } 
`

Comment: Sorry, may I know the reason why I can't use [types_of_infection="Cases reported are decreasing or circulation is ongoing"] {
   
   marker-fill: #ffff00;
   marker-width: 15;
   marker-line-color: #000000;
   marker-line-width: 20;
   marker-line-opacity: 1;
}

Comment: There is something wrong on my cartodb system. When I use the property marker-line-width for my disaster map https://sengyapglobalmomentum.cartodb.com/viz/3fc388fa-2247-11e6-9661-0e3ff518bd15/public_map, it works perfectly fine. However, when I use the property marker-line-width for my surveillance map https://sengyapglobalmomentum.cartodb.com/viz/e9c2796a-fbcd-11e5-8d27-0ecfd53eb7d3/public_map, the marker line appears as a transparent bubble (I did not set any transparency effect). Why is this so?

Comment: If you think this question is solved please, click on the up-arrow. Then, please because this is a one question/answer forum I recommend you to ask a new question. Also, you have to add all the info you have in order to help us. When you are styling a map, the best practice is to copy and paste the whole CartoCSS code (in your case, from your two maps).

Comment: Ok, I will post a new question on this. Thanks @ramiroaznar.

Answer (score 0):

Set first the color and then select an image if you want to use just the wizard, but at the end, the CartoCSS code will lo  /** simple visualization */

```
#test_3{
    marker-file: url(http://com.cartodb.users-assets.production.s3.amazonaws.com/simpleicon/flag31.svg);
    marker-fill-opacity: 0.9;
    marker-placement: point;
    marker-width: 10;
    marker-fill: #B81609;
}
```

So you see, you have the marker file but also the fill properties to set image and color respectively.

Comment: Does this work if I am using a category map?

Comment: Do you know how to change the marker line width? This is the URL https://sengyapglobalmomentum.cartodb.com/viz/e9c2796a-fbcd-11e5-8d27-0ecfd53eb7d3/public_map I am using. I cannot seem to increase the marker line width despite changing it to 20.